# AngularJS not updating when callback called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having a weird issue with `AngularJS` not updating my view when I update the `controller` vars in a callback:

**payment.controller.js**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  //TODO: Declare the Cover module
  angular.module('payment', []);

  //TODO: Declare the controller of Cover module
  angular.module('payment').controller('PaymentController', function factory() {
    var _this = this;

    _this.pay = event => {
      event.preventDefault();
      if(_this.Card.Expiration != null && _this.Card.CVC != null && _this.Card.CardNumber != null){
        Stripe.card.createToken({
          number: _this.Card.CardNumber,
          cvc: _this.Card.CVC,
          exp_month: _this.Card.Expiration.split('/')[0],
          exp_year: _this.Card.Expiration.split('/')[1]
        }, myFunc);

        // This doesn't work
        function myFunc(){
          _this.ErrorMessage = 'Error';
        };

        // But this does
        myFunc();
      } else {
        _this.ErrorMessage = 'Check the card data please';
      }
    };
  }
})();
```

**route.js**

```
.when('/payment',{
  templateUrl: 'pay/pay.html',
  controller:'PaymentController',
  controllerAs: 'payment'
})
```

**pay.html** (The relevant bit)

```
<div class="form__errors" ng-show="payment.errorFlag">
  <p>{{payment.ErrorMessage}}</p>
</div>
```

_this is in scope, and I can see it updating in console. I'm running `Angular 1.6.`

Comment: How is your view defined? You should try to provide all relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to call `$scope.$appy()` when the callback has updated your component's model.

Inject `$scope` into your controller and call `$scope.$apply()` in `myFunc`.